# How to target array values - php xml

Tags: php, xml

I've hit a wall with parsing this XML and am hoping for some insight into how to solve this. I can't seem to target all three ID's to loop over:

**Source XML**

```
?xml version="1.0" ?>
<items xmlns="http://schemas.example.com/item" xmlns:os="http://example.com/-/1.0/">
        <os:startIndex>0</os:startIndex>
        <os:itemsPerPage>1</os:itemsPerPage>
        <os:totalResults>1</os:totalResults>
  <item>
    <reservations>
      <reservation-reference id="12345"></reservation-reference>
      <reservation-reference id="54321"></reservation-reference>
      <reservation-reference id="67891"></reservation-reference>
    </reservations>
  </item>
</items>
```

**PHP code snippet**

```
$call_resList = './multi-res.xml';
$resList = simpleXML_load_file($call_resList,"SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
            
    foreach($resList->item as $aA) {
      $parent = $aA->reservations;
      var_export($parent);

      echo "<br/><br/>";

      $child = $aA->reservations->{'reservation-reference'};
      var_export($child);
      }
```

**$parent Output**

```
    SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( 'reservation-reference' => array 
( 0 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( '@attributes' => array ( 'id' => '12345', ), )), 
  1 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( '@attributes' => array ( 'id' => '54321', ), )), 
  2 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( '@attributes' => array ( 'id' => '67891', ), )), 
  ), ))
```

As soon as I step down into ->{'reservation-reference'} array, I loose the other elements.

**$child Output**

```
   SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( '@attributes' => array ( 'id' => '12345', ), ))
```

Any pointers to help me on my way would be gratefully received.

Comment: Just loop over `$aA->reservations->{'reservation-reference'}` again.

Comment: Thanks 04FS, I've tried it using the following:

`foreach($resList->item->reservations->{'reservation-reference'} as $aA) {
    echo $bB;
}`
...but it doesn't work - 500 error. Was that what you were recommending by looping over?

Thanks

Comment: And `$bB` is supposed to come from where …?

Comment: Don’t use `echo` to try and output full simplexml objects, that might show you nothing. Use `var_dump` for debug outputs.

Comment: oh, apologies.. $aA! Still throws a 500 error.

Comment: `foreach($resList->item->reservations->{'reservation-reference'} as $aA) { echo $aA['id']; }` works for me, with the XML you have shown (only read from string instead of a file, but that should make little difference.)

Comment: `$aA['id']` is still a SimpleXMLElement at this point, but echo-ing it works. If you need to use these values in other contexts though, it would be recommendable to explicitly cast them to string first, otherwise you might run into problems.

Comment: Thanks 04FS, $aA['id'] did the trick! Many thanks!